# Using DropZone to upload the Facebook Profile image, Max 1 upload

Tags: dropzone.js

I am grabbing the Facebook profile pict on a page and loading it locally to the server and then pulling it into DropZone using the emit function. What I want to do is limit the number of files available in the  dropzone to 1. In other words, if they want to remove the pre loaded Facebook they can put can then only load one more image. Below is my code

```
     var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".dropzone");
             Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
                 maxFiles: 1,
                 init: function () {
                  this.on("complete", function (data) {
                     var res = eval('(' + data.xhr.responseText + ')');
                    });
                   }
                };
             mockFile = {name:"image.jpg", size:9};
             // Call the default addedfile event handler
             myDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
            // And optionally show the thumbnail of the file:
             myDropzone.emit("thumbnail", mockFile, "/usf/jsSDK/uploads/image.jpg");
```

1. My preloaded image doesnt seem to have a remove option on it
2. My limit 1 in the options doesnt seem to be working.
   Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `maxfilesexceeded` event to remove the file currently on the dropzone and add the current file, something like (inside `init`)

```
this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(new_file) {
    this.removeAllFiles();
    this.addFile(new_file);
});
```

About the remove button on the file, its hard to tell without the having a look at the callback `addedfile`. If you can post that as well, that will be helpful.